# Facebook like a post

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, objective-c-blocks

i am trying to add like button on my application in ios . when i hit url in graph api explorer it works fine, and give me response true. but when i hit this in my code nothing happened

```
(void)likeFacebookPost:(NSString*)likeID
{

    NSString *theWholeUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                  @"%@/%@/likes&access_token=%@",
                                                  GRAPH_API_BASEURL,likeID,
                                                  [_facebookToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];



    NSURL *facebookUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:theWholeUrl];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:facebookUrl];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];

    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);

}
```